Can science inform philosophy?
Philosophy can sometimes inform science. After all, science was once called natural philosophy, and the scientific method is a creation of philosophy. However, does the arrow of influence go both ways? That is, can science inform philosophical thinking and discussion? I would also like to know what philosophers, especially philosophers of science, have written about this matter.

Is implies can, so yes. And philosophy of science is obviously informed by science or it would not be philosophy of science. Can you explain in more detail what sort of informing you are interested in because on generic reading the question is perplexing.

Science BETTER inform philosophy. If philosophy is entirely unaffected by chemistry and physics and neuroscience and consciousness studies, then philosophy is lost

If science can't influence Philosophy, then Philosophy amounts to a religion, a set of foregone conclusions acquired from old books.

There seems to be some reluctance among philosophers to accept the results of science, if they are in conflict with their philosophical views. There seems to be a lack of interest in facts. Opinions of established philosophers are held in much higher regard. Facts are often mistaken for opinions.

I have yet to see signs that the majority of philosophers are willing to consider any input from reality. Plato started a very successful trend that limits philosophy to people who are paying more attention to their own egos than to their ears and eyes.

The answer, which is too short for SE rules, is "no".

Groovy got to it first, but the notion that philosophical knowledge intersects with scientific fact is naturalized epistemology which enjoys a range of belief from mutually supportive but distinct domains to absolutely no discontinuity between them. The shorter and easier to read article is WP's Naturalized Epistemology:

Naturalized epistemology (a term coined by W. V. O. Quine) is a collection of philosophic views about the theory of knowledge that emphasize the role of natural scientific methods. This shared emphasis on scientific methods of studying knowledge shifts the focus of epistemology away from many traditional philosophical questions, and towards the empirical processes of knowledge acquisition.

Two additional articles that are progressively more difficult to read are:

Naturalistic Epistemology (IEP)
Naturalism in Epistemology (SEP)

It's been my experience that the best way to move in the direction of naturalizing your epistemology is to study the philosophy of science. Two additional articles are:

Metaphysics of Science (IEP)
Science and Pseudo-Science (SEP)

Thus, one can reason about knowledge and do it using the facts of science. In this way reason itself has a foot in both worlds.

The very foundation of reason (logic) is an abstraction of physical observations. I rarely meet people with interest in philosophy who even know that much about it. The problem with philosophy is not philosophy itself. It's the kind of people it attracts. Those who care about scientific reasoning are going into science, or at least mathematics. The philosophy departments, OTOH, are filled with people who can't even tell what they are doing there.

I googled for some examples of what you ask.
W.V.O. Quine "Two Dogmas of Empiricism" (1951), Quine argued for a naturalized epistemology, suggesting that philosophy should be continuous with science.
Thomas Kuhn "The Structure of Scientific Revolutions" (1962) explored how scientific paradigms shift, influencing both philosophy of science and broader philosophical discussions.
Hilary Putnam argued for scientific realism and the importance of scientific knowledge in philosophical inquiry.
Daniel Dennett often bridges philosophy and cognitive science, demonstrating how scientific findings can inform philosophical debates about consciousness and free will.
Patricia Churchland argues that neuroscientific findings should inform our philosophical understanding of the mind.
Elliott Sober shows how evolutionary theory can inform philosophical discussions on topics like altruism and group selection.
Nancy Cartwright emphasizes the importance of understanding scientific practice and its implications for philosophical theories.
Philip Kitcher has written extensively on how science can inform ethics and social philosophy, particularly in his book "Science, Truth, and Democracy" (2001).

@andrós, absit iniuria, an excellent point! SE should have this feature where ChatGPT or another AI (1 should suffice) "posts" an answer. What say you, mods?

@Hudjefa If you want to destroy the site, go right ahead. All current AIs are hallucinating harder than a schizophrenic person on a combination of magic mushrooms and LSD.

@FlatterMann, doesn't it depend on the quality of the data AI was trained on? GIGO! To be clear, given the answers I've seen from AI, the training data was not something the developers compromised on (must've cost a fortune).

No, it doesn't. Current generation LLMs are designed to pretend that they are smart. That doesn't make them smart, but they are very good at the pretending part... just like many philosophers, I am afraid. Having said that, try to ask questions about quantum mechanics from an AI and then compare to nature. You will see that the AIs are giving false answers because they were trained on data that is false. In case of science an AI would have to be trained on empirical data and that hasn't happened, yet.

When philosophy deals with topics that are not easily quantifiable, it will be harder to argue that the exact sciences would provide useful input.  On the other hand, when philosophy deals with topics generally recognized as being in the domain of the exact sciences, such a task becomes easier.  Thus, mathematics can actually provide refutation of a philosopher's claims.
To take an example, nobody will deny that Bertrand Russell is considered to be a distinguished philosopher.  Similarly, nobody will deny that infinitesimals have a role in the exact sciences.  It turns out that Russell's claims concerning infinitesimals were definitively refuted by subsequent scientific developments.  More specifically, Russell claimed the following:

"Infinitesimals as explaining continuity must be regarded as unnecessary, erroneous, and self-contradictory." (The Principles of Mathematics, 1903, item 324).

Similarly,

"the so-called infinitesimal calculus ... has nothing to do with the infinitesimal." (op. cit., item 308).

Following the developments in infinitesimal analysis in the 1960s and 1970s, few scholars today would adhere to such views, which can be considered as soundly refuted.

Is "infinitesimal analysis" science? It seems to be mathematics.

@JimmyJames, I used the term "exact science" inclusively (both mathematics and natural science).  The distinction is not that significant for our purposes because infinitesimals are routinely used in physics and other natural sciences, as well.

@MikhailKatz But scientific evidence suggests that infinitesimals are not part of reality or at the very least, there's no evidence that infinitesimals are real. " infinitesimals are routinely used in physics" this is a non-sequitur.  Grammar and composition are used in science as well but that doesn't make them a form of science.

Nothing that Russel was interested in exists in the real world. In physics everything is an approximation. We teach that to physicists in their very first theoretical physics lesson. I have yet to see a philosopher who understands the profound consequences of that... or who can accept them. Scientists can and do work with things that are 100% wrong (like Newtonian mechanics) because they are "right enough" for the task at hand, which might be something as trivial as flying to the moon. Philosophy will never fly you to the moon. It's too desperate to be 100% right 100% of the time.

@Jim, Leibniz realized already 348 years ago that infinitesimals are not to be found in nature. Nevertheless, they are useful in both mathematics and physics.  Aristotle and others were using "Grammar and composition" for thousands of years in attempts to do physics without however making much progress, until infinitesimal calculus came on the scene in the 17th century.

@MikhailKatz The fact remains that mathematics is not 'science', at least the way we understand 'science' today.  Mathematics is also used in business.  Does that make mathematics a business?  Mathematics is used in engineering.  Does that make mathematics a type of engineering?  Mathematics is used in cooking.  Does that make mathematics a form of cooking?

Mathematics is an exact science.

It is a bi-directional influence. Philosophy influences Science and Science influences Philosophy. The distinction between the two is also "blurred". Take theoretical physics for example it is the application of logic, math and philosophy within the constraints of physics. It is the application of these philosophical tools to interpret the data and empirical evidence we obtain from physicists to give meaning to the findings, that we call theoretical physics. And again with our new formalizations of theories we have founded we influence (give/provide a direction) for the improvement and perfection of tools to obtain more scientific data and evidence.

Classical philosophy searches for the truth. Science is founded on natural philosophy. Quantum physics is throwing up ideas which require philosophical investigation. So, yes, science and philosophy need to work together to search for the truth.

Science can provide interesting elements to philosophers, specially when it comes to paradoxes. It provides strong examples of ancient beliefs that science prooved to be false: the earth was long expected to be flat, then the center of the world. Said differently, it gives an interesting point of view where what was taught by ancient scholars who were highly respected can be false of rejected.
Among the examples, the Newtonian physics was expected to explain the whole mechanics of the world... until we realized that we need the relativity to explain the movement of Mercury around the sun. Or on a more fundamental mathematics point of view, Euclidian geometry ensures that through a point exterior to a straight line passes one and only one straight line parallel to a given direction. Which is understandable by primary school students, and evident to many adults. Refuting that axiom leaded to the Rieman geometry that happens to be highly important in the equations of relativity theory.
What I mean is that because science constantly evolves, if gives philosophers good reasons to question everything people (including themselves) believe, with examples proving that this questioning is essential.

Yes of course science should inform philosophy.
People have been philosophizing for thousands of years, if not significantly longer. Let me just remind you some of the things which the ancients did not have the benefit of knowing when thinking about humans and what sort of lives we should lead and how we should relate to each other. All of which we have learned through science over the past centuries.
We have learned that humans are made out of cells, and that cells are made out of molecules whose enormously complicated interactions with each other produce this fantastic emergent phenomenon of life. We have learned that quantum field theory, and in particular the Standard Model of particle physics, accurately explain all of these interactions and the emergent phenomena arising from them, from nuclear physics to chemistry to DNA replication to respiration and digestion.
We have learned that the Earth is some 4.5 billion years old, in sharp contrast to many early worldviews which maintained existence began more-or-less yesterday.
We have learned that all life we see originates from biochemical reactions on the early Earth leading to the formation of self-replicating cells, and that every single living organism we’ve found has a common ancestor a few hundred million years after the formation of the Earth.
We have learned that the Earth we see today is the product of significant processing by life, and that for some couple billion years single-celled microbes spread throughout every corner of Earth and very gradually transformed it from a ball of rock to a mound rich in organic material.
We have learned that all animals share a common ancestor less than a billion years ago and that each of us had a common ancestor with all mammals a couple hundred million years ago—every cat and dog kept as a pet, every ox and donkey we put to work, every sheep and pig we raise and slaughter.
We have learned that every single human is related just in the past couple hundred thousand years, which is an incredibly tiny fraction of the age of the universe. We have learned that our ancestors have been social primates for millions of years, depending on each other to lead successful lives.
We have learned that humans’ collectives actions can influence the large scale climate of the Earth and have enormous effects on its biosphere.
We have learned that the Sun is but one of some hundred billion stars in our Milky Way galaxy, and that within the observable universe there are some 1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 different planets—and this is just the small part of the universe which we have been in causal contact with.
We have learned that the protons and neutrons composing all of our atoms formed out of a hot primordial soup some five minutes after the hot big bang, 13.7 billion years ago, once the Standard Model plasma cooled below the nuclear binding energies.
We have learned that the universe shortly after the hot big bang was incredibly uniform, and the small inhomogeneities had grown by gravitational instabilities over a few hundred thousand years to a part in ten thousand by the era of recombination when the temperature fell below atomic binding energies and hydrogen and helium atoms could form. That gravity took further hundreds of millions of years to form the first stars and galaxies.
We have learned that every heavy element in our bodies and on Earth was formed in the nuclear furnace of a star some billions of years before the solar system existed, before being liberated from the star’s gravitational well in a stellar explosion which belched it out into the cloud of dust from which we eventually formed.
Many areas of philosophy deal with understanding who we are as humans, how we should relate to each other and other organisms and the Earth, how we should organize societies, and what sort of lives should we lead. Now obviously just learning science does not directly answer these questions, nor is science the only sort of input needed for properly understanding them. But it seems equally obvious to me that our revolutionary scientific knowledge of the universe and of ourselves should inform these questions. Over the past decades and centuries we have learned enormous amounts about the fundamental world and ‘what’s going on here’. If the understanding of the world that the ancients had led to some Bayesian distribution on philosophical propositions and arguments which we might accept, certainly understanding all of this fundamental information about the universe should effect an enormous Bayesian update factor. Certainly it has had such an effect on near every area of my own thinking.

When I was at the University I attended a philosophy class aimed towards computer science students. One of the key points that our philosophy professor wanted us to take home from the class was the following:

Before computers, all functions of the brain, including reasoning, were a mystery. (Often attributed to the famous god of the gaps.)
With the advent of computers, the computer folks essentially showed the philosophers how, starting with the humble logic gate, you can build layer upon layer of functionality to arrive at a machine that can perform basic functions of reasoning, so there you go, it is not a mystery anymore. (And the god of the gaps has receded from yet one more gap.)


That having been said, let me add that the arrow does not go both ways; it only goes one way: science informs philosophy, philosophy does not inform science.  It is precisely the realization that philosophy should not, must not, better not inform science that caused the term "natural philosophy" to be dropped like a hot potato.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
